# Deleting row and reordering indices from table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

We have a feature that we can delete line from a table through the function below.

```
function setDeleteItemButtonBehavior() {
    $(document).on('click', '.delete-boxItem', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //$(this).removeClass('.delete-boxItem');
        //showLoadingDialog();
        var type = $(this).data('type');
        var oTable = type == "U" ? TableR : TableS;

        if (oTable.fnGetData().length > 0) {
            //$(this).closest("tr").remove();
            var nRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
            oTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow);
            updateReceivedItemLabelWhenRemove();
            controlDeleteItem(type, oTable);
            var deleteIndex = parseInt($(nRow).find("input[name*='Index']").val());
            var tagRemove = parseInt($(nRow).find("input[name*='Tag']").val());
            updateTagItemOrder(type, deleteIndex, tagRemove, true);
        }
        //makeModalContentInvisible();
    });
}
```

Because of the other logics that occur in the deletion as reordering of the lines and tags Internet Explorer ends up crashing, because the script takes too long to run. Would anyone have another suggestion on how to optimize this functionality? Below is an example of the method of reordering of the indices:

```
 function controlDeleteItem(type, oTable) {

    var grid = oTable.fnGetNodes();

    $.each(grid, function (index, value) {
        $(value).find('input[name$=".Index"]').val(index);

        $(value).find('input, div, span').each(function () {

            if ($(this).attr('id')) {
                var boxItems = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[0];
                var field= $(this).attr('id').split("__")[1];
                $(this).attr('id', boxItems + '_' + index + '__' + field);
            }

            if ($(this).attr('name')) {
                var boxItems = $(this).attr('name').split("[")[0];
                var field = $(this).attr('name').split("]")[1];
                $(this).attr('name', boxItems + '[' + index + ']' + field);
            }

            if ($(this).data('valmsg-for')) {
                var boxItems = $(this).data('valmsg-for').split("[")[0];
                var field = $(this).data('valmsg-for').split("]")[1];
                $(this).data('valmsg-for', boxItems + '[' + index + ']' + field);
            }

        });

        $(value).find('button[id^="btnSetWarrantyLostReason_R"]').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('id', 'btnSetWarrantyLostReason_R' + index);
        });

    });
}


function prepareDataTable() {
    oTableR = $('table.data-table-r').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aoColumns": [{ "sClass": "" }, { "sClass": "" }, { "sClass": "" }, { "sClass": "" }, { "sClass": "" },
                      { "sClass": "align-text-center align-center" }, { "sClass": "" },
                      { "sClass": "align-text-center align-center" }, { "sClass": "align-text-center" }, { "sClass": "align-text-center" }]
    });

    oTableS = $('table.data-table-s').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aoColumns": [{ "sClass": "" }, { "sClass": "" }, { "sClass": "" }, { "sClass": "" }, { "sClass": "" },
                      { "sClass": "align-text-center align-center" }, { "sClass": "" },
                      { "sClass": "align-text-center align-center" }, { "sClass": "align-text-center" }, { "sClass": "align-text-center" }]
    });
}
```

The above function is the assembly of my DataTables object.

Comment: you might need to add the respective HTML for this purpose, the exact one which crashes and the steps to replicate it

Comment: it would be better to create a minimal example which replicates the issue, as the problem could be in any of the functions used

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in your id construction.

If you can just change your id construction.
If you can't you should consider because it will save you a few neurons. (You should not want to shift an id from one item to another...).

Naming your id with an increasing fashion can serve two purposes:

1. having an ordered/comparable collection
2. having an easy distance calculation between two elements

To satisfy 1. it is actually trivial: juste make an id with a timestamp

```
id = Date.now()+'_'+(z++)%1000 //the z part in case you create several items at the same timestamp
```

Obviously better to use a `guid` or an `ObjectId`

To satisfy 2. 
juste use an array along your DOM

```
myIds = []
myIds.splice(myIds.indexOf(yourId), 1)//delete
myIds.push(yourId)//add
var d = (aId,bId)=> myIds.indexOf(bId) - myIds.indexOf(aId)
```

attr name and valmsg-for should not semantically include the "index" part but if forced, you can do the same

Comment: I use the datatables to currently control the table, but deleting a line takes a long time when the table has 600 or more rows...